# Why is rows undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport-local

Creating a user registration functionality using Passport(Local-Signup), code  below:

```
// config/passport.js

// load all the things we need
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;

// load up the user model
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var dbconfig = require('./database');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig.connection);

connection.query('USE ' + dbconfig.database);
// expose this function to our app using module.exports
module.exports = function(passport) {


    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? ",[id], function(err, rows){
            done(err, rows[0]);
        });
    });


    passport.use(
        'local-signup',
        new LocalStrategy({
            // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
            usernameField : 'username',
            passwordField : 'password',
            passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
        },
        function(req, username, password, done) {
            // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
            // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
            connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?",[username], function(err, rows) {
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                if (rows.length) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That username is already taken.'));
                } else {
                    // if there is no user with that username
                    // create the user
                    var newUserMysql = {
                        username: username,
                        password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, null, null)  // use the generateHash function in our user model
                    };

                    var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password ) values (?,?)";

                    connection.query(insertQuery,[newUserMysql.username, newUserMysql.password],function(err, rows) {
                        newUserMysql.id = rows.insertId;

                        return done(null, newUserMysql);
                    });
                }
            });
        })
    );
```

throws the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>       at Query._callback (M:\server\config\passport.js:70:55)
>       at Query.Sequence.end (M:\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:88:24)
>       at Query.ErrorPacket (M:\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:90:8)
>       at Protocol._parsePacket (M:\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:279:23)
>       at Parser.write (M:\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
>       at Protocol.write (M:\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
>       at Socket. (M:\server\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:103:28)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
>       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
>       at TCP.onread (net.js:594:20)

Using `console.log(rows);` returns `undefined`. How can I address this issue?

**[EDIT]**
After answer was taken into account the following error was produced (because `rows.insertId` is **still** undefined):

> Error: Failed to serialize user into session
>       at pass (M:\server\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:281:19)
>       at serialized (M:\server\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:286:7)
>       at M:\server\config\passport.js:24:9
>       at pass (M:\server\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:294:9)
>       at Authenticator.serializeUser (M:\server\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:299:5)
>       at SessionManager.logIn (M:\server\node_modules\passport\lib\sessionmanager.js:14:8)
>       at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (M:\server\node_modules\passport\lib\http\request.js:50:33)
>       at Strategy.strategy.success (M:\server\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:248:13)
>       at verified (M:\server\node_modules\passport-local\lib\strategy.js:83:10)

Comment: Does `err` contain something?

Comment: @El_Matella nope error is null. Re-running the code produced another error now: `Error: Failed to serialize user into session`

Comment: where is `newUserMysql ` coming from ?

Comment: @Ravi it's just a local var in JSON format. `var newUserMysql = {username: username, password : password};`

Comment: @Valamorde can you share the json as well for reference ?

Comment: please show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE users` seem you have `id INT NOT NULL` but not `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: @Alex id is `INT NOT NULL ZEROFILL AUTOINCREMENT` and `PRIMARY`

Comment: @Ravi it's in my comment

Comment: what type and value is your var `newUserMysql` ?

Comment: @Alex  local var in JSON format. `var newUserMysql = {username: username, password : password};`

Comment: I don't see that in the code fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was under my nose under the whole time. All I had to do was to change this:

```
newUserMysql = rows.insertId;
```

into this:

```
newUserMysql = rows[0].insertId;
```

and the issue was resolved successfully.

Comment: Just note that this will fail if rows is undefined or an empty array. So you might want to handle that somehow.

Comment: @Bergur In general yes it would, in my case the error was thrown because I was accessing an element property without specifying the element&#39;s index. Once that was fixed it has never been undefined or empty for almost 8 months now :p

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding, it is nothing to do with `MySQL`

The JSON, which you shared doesn't have `id`

> var newUserMysql = {username: username, password : password};

whereas, you are trying to access `id` and that's the reason, you getting `undefined`

```
newUserMysql.id = rows.insertId;
```

To solve this issue, you need to add `id` to your JSON.

```
var newUserMysql = {username: "username", password : "password", id:""};
```

Comment: nope, that's not it! I tried it and the error remains `Failed to serialize user into session`. Could it be that the` id `field is zerofilled?

Comment: @Valamorde because your serialization doesn't expect `id`. You are no more getting mentioned exception. Now, we don't have complete picture of your application. Whatever, you will share, we will answer accordingly.

Comment: @Valamorde this is not how you should change your question completely. If your problem was solved an getting some other issue. Then, you are supposed to accept the answer and create new post with other detail. Now, context of my answer  will change completely

Comment: @Valamorde Also, don't forget to revert your question. Otherwise, people get confused.

Comment: @Valamorde I have rollbacked to initial question.

Comment: Sure, but problem persists, it's failing to serialize the user because `rows.insertId`is `undefined`

Comment: @Valamorde I don't know, whether you get my point initially. I said, your original question doesn't even have single word about `serialization`. So, that's altogether different issue.

Comment: @Valamorde `Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` this was the error, which is shared in your original question. How would I know, if you get serialization issue ? Now, since, this problem was resolved, you started getting another issue.

Comment: You 're probably missing mine, `rows.insertId` is still undefined, so the answer you provided does not resolve the issue

Comment: @Valamorde No, I completely got your point. I addressed your error (which you shared stacktrace) in my answer. If you have provided stacktrace for serialization issue, then I would have answered accordingly.

Comment: @Valamorde If you recall my earlier comment, I never said, my answer will fix all the issue. But, it will fix the error, which is mentioned in your original question. And, if you getting some other issue, then you are supposed to post new post. But, before that, you need to close this post, by accepting it.

Comment: @Valamorde i'm not going to argue further. I'm glad your problem is solved. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer is invalid because of the following reason: if `rows.insertId` is undefined then it doesn't matter if `newUserMysql` contains an`id` field. So the issue has not been addressed properly. Especially since i am using `console.log(rows)` and not `console.log(newUserMysql)`

Comment: @Valamorde are you saying, without declaring another property `id` in JSON. You are code is working ?? If that is the case, then why didn't you posted serialization  issue earlier ? How on earth javascript will know the `id` property in `newUserMysql ` can you explain ?

Comment: @Valamorde you are talking all non-sense. I'm not going to argue further. All the best to you to get best answer in future.

Comment: Jesus, It doesn't need to know it up to the point of my question, I'm printing out  the `rows` variable which is undefined not the JSON itself.